# What are the gradients computed when doing backpropagation (training) in nn.MultiheadAttention?

Tags: pytorch

This is my understanding of how training process works inside `nn.MultiheadAttention`. Lets ignore position encoding and lets only focus on `Q` case.

`batch = 1,num_heads = 2, seq_len = 5, problem_dim = 4.`

`word_embedding = [5,4]`
`q_weight = [4x4]`
`Q = word_embedding*q_weight`

Assume,

```
 class MultiHeadAttentionModel(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, problem_dim, num_heads):
            super().__init__()
            self.multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim=problem_dim,num_heads=num_heads,batch_first=True)
        
        def forward(self, query, key, value):
            attn_output, attn_output_weights = self.multihead_attn(query, key, value)
            return attn_output, attn_output_weights

model = MultiHeadAttentionModel(problem_dim=problem_dim, num_heads=num_heads)
model.eval()          <---------------- forward pass
attn_output, attn_output_weights = model(Q, K, V)
attn_output.backward() <--------------- training (backward pass)

final_linear_weight = model.multihead_attn.out_proj.weight
```

There is final linear transformation of `output = (softmax(Q.dot(K_trans).dot(V))*final_linear_weight` *Ignore the scalings for now*

My question is, is `final_linear_weight` the only weight that is being learned during the training phase?

Comment: Can you be more precise, what do you mean by including "the computation of the backward weights"? Are you asking whether it's possible to train a multi-head attention?

Comment: To me the question does not make sense, the OP seems to be taking shortcuts on how gradients are actually computed (i.e. missing notation for gradients).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#MultiheadAttention) for the multihead attention module.

The weights learned are the projection layers for the query, key, and value inputs, in projection bias, out projection weight, and out projection bias.

Comment: So, `in_proj_weight` : `q_weights`, `k_weights` and `v_weights` are used to create Q, K and V. `in_proj_weight` is used to create `attn_output`. Where `O=(softmax(Q.dot(K_trans).dot(V))`, `attn_out = O*out_proj.weight`